# Is it possible to install a pre-imaged PWA for 100% offline use?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My company has a PWA and we recently received an interesting business opportunity: a certain organization wants to purchase a volume license and pre-install the app on a very large number of computers, some of which may *never* go online, because they're going to areas of rural poverty and lack of access to the Internet, for example.

In addition to avoiding the need for download, we want to do this via pre-image so that we can provide a standardized environment, and not have everyone installing the PWA to different locations or not knowing how to install, even if they were connected.

Of course, the normal PWA workflow is to install and load assets onto the machine via download, at least one time up front, but this would only work if you could guarantee some initial window of connectivity.

Is there any way to accomplish the pre-install as I'm describing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to check into Enterprise IT level tools for something like this. Those tools can normally pre-configure a device with an image.
The user would of course still need to authenticate in your application.
The real problem is the application will need to update every so often.
Honestly if it were me I would configure the image with a local, default home page, say in Edge for desktop, and have links to the targeted PWAs. From there they can install.
For me, most applications, even real large ones, can be completely rendered and installed in a couple of seconds on normal cellular connectivity.
I did this for a couple of conferences I went to last year:
https://love2dev.com/pwa/pubcon/

I will ping some folks about the preconfigured image and get back to you if they answer me.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'd definitely appreciate any further resources you could end.